# Angular reactive form - I want to get a form property and check if its dirty and pristine

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular7, angular-forms

Angular reactive form - I want to get a form property and check if its dirty and pristine.

**Tech**: angular 7 and reactive forms.

**My form:**

```
 <form class="flex flex-wrap col-12" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">

  <input type="text" placeholder="Company Name*" formControlName="companyName" class="col-12 field">

  <div formGroupName="address" class="col-12 mb1">

      <input class="col-12 field field-google" type="text" placeholder="Your Location*" id="Location" [options]='options' formControlName="addressLine1">

  </div>
</form>
```

I want form.address.addressLine1 and form.companyName checked to see if they are dirty and pristine in the html so I can show an error message.

**Current attempt:**

```
<p *ngIf="form.address.addressLine1.dirty">Error....</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a FormGroup you can access the children using the `controls` property. Which is a map.

```
<p *ngIf="form.controls['address'].controls['addressLine1'].dirty">Error....</p>
```

You have two nested groups. So you have to use controls twice.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls

Answer (score 1):

Not what you asked but you can also use the HTML CSS classes.

example:

```
/* VALID */
form.ng-dirty {
    input {
        &.ng-valid.ng-dirty:not(.ng-pristine){
            p {
               display: none;
            }
        }
    }
}    
/* INVALID */
    form.ng-dirty {
        input {
            &.ng-invalid.ng-dirty:not(.ng-pristine){
                p {
                   display: block;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the controls using `get()` like below:

`<p *ngIf="form.get('address').get('addressLine1').dirty">Error....</p>`

Similarly, you can access companyName like:
`<p *ngIf="form.get('companyName').dirty">Error....</p>`